# Flutter dragable issue

Tags: flutter, draggable

`List<Widget> draggableWidgets = [];`
 `bool _dragging = false;`
`double _x = 0;`
 `double _y = 0;`

`void addDraggableWidget() {`
`setState(() {`
 `draggableWidgets.add(`
  `Positioned(`
  `left: _x,`
  `top: _y,`
`child: Draggable(`
  `feedback: Container(`
 `width: 100,`
`height: 100,` color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.7),  child: const Center( child: Text( '',   style: TextStyle(  color: Colors.white,   fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,  ),  ),   ),   ),  onDragStarted: () {    setState(() {     _dragging = true;    });  },  onDragEnd: (details) {    setState(() {     _dragging = false;    _x = details.offset.dx;     _y = details.offset.dy;    });   },   child: Container(     width: 70,     height: 80,     color: Colors.blue,    child: Column(   children: [     Text(""), //selectedData[index]['number']     Text("cd"), //selectedData[index]['tbsize'].toString()     IconButton(    icon: Icon(Icons.remove),    onPressed: () { `

```
                `   setState(() {}); `
               `  }, `
               `), `
          `   ], `
        `   )), `
    ` ), `
 `  )); `
```

`});`
 `}`

`IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.add),onPressed: () {` 
`addDraggableWidget();`
 `setState(() {});)}`